# How to update an array of state using useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I want to get latest state after updating state.
So I need to use `useEffect`.

After I change content of todo, I call `saveEditedTodo`  onBlur.
So my code is,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(todos)
    // I need to setTodos(todos), but it causes infinite loop

  }, [todos]);

  const saveEditedTodo = (e, id) => {
    const newContent = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;

    const editedTodo = todos.map((todo) =>
      todo.id === id ? { ...todo, todoItem: newContent } : todo,
    );

    setTodos(editedTodo); // Re-rendering
    onBlur(todos);  // Re-rendering
  };
```

And `onBlur` from props is,

```js
  const handleOnBlurTodo = (value) => {
    const newValue = convertTodoToNote(value);
    setEditableNote({ ...editableNote, content: newValue });
  };
```

How can I get latest state using useEffect?

(+) Here is my full code!

```js
function TodoList({ todoContent, onBlur }) {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(todoContent);
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState({ hoverID: '', onHover: false });
  const { hoverID, onHover } = isHover;

  const isEditable = useSelector((state) => state.isSelected);
  const doneTodo = todos ? todos.filter((todo) => todo.isDone).length : 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(todos);
  }, [todos]);


  const saveEditedTodo = (e, id) => {
    const newContent = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;

    const editedTodo = todos.map((todo) =>
      todo.id === id ? { ...todo, todoItem: newContent } : todo,
    );

    setTodos(editedTodo); // Re-rendering
    onBlur(todos); // Re-rendering
  };

  const handleDeleteTodo = (id) => {
    let newTodos = todos.filter((el) => el.id !== id);
    setTodos(newTodos);
    onBlur(todos);
  };

  const handleOnMouseOver = (id) => {
    setIsHover({ hoverID: id, onHover: true });
  };

  const handleOnMouseLeave = (id) => {
    setIsHover({ hoverID: id, onHover: false });
  };

  const handleCheckbox = (id) => {
    const newTodos = todos.map((todo) =>
      todo.id === id ? { ...todo, isDone: !todo.isDone } : todo,
    );
    setTodos(newTodos);
    console.log('[todos]' + todos);
  };

  const todoTask = todos.filter((todo) => !todo.isDone);
  const doneTask = todos.filter((todo) => todo.isDone);

  if (isEditable && todos) {
    let todoList = todoTask.map((todo, i) => (
      <TodoListContainer
        key={i}
        onMouseEnter={() => handleOnMouseOver(todo.id)}
        onMouseLeave={() => handleOnMouseLeave(todo.id)}
      >
        <Checkbox
          type="checkbox"
          checked={todo.isDone}
          onChange={() => handleCheckbox(todo.id)}
        />
        <NoteTitle
          isTodoItem
          size="medium"
          placeholder="Add Todo"
          onBlur={(e) => saveEditedTodo(e, todo.id)}
          contentEditable
          suppressContentEditableWarning="true"
        >
          {todo.todoItem}
        </NoteTitle>
        {hoverID === todo.id && onHover && (
          <Tool
            title="Delete Todo"
            bgImage={DeleteIcon}
            deleteTodo={() => handleDeleteTodo(todo.id)}
          />
        )}
      </TodoListContainer>
    ));

    let doneList = doneTask.map((todo, i) => (
      <TodoListContainer
        key={i}
        onMouseEnter={() => handleOnMouseOver(todo.id)}
        onMouseLeave={() => handleOnMouseLeave(todo.id)}
      >
        <Checkbox
          type="checkbox"
          onBlur={() => handleCheckbox(todo.id)}
          checked={todo.isDone}
        />
        <NoteTitle
          isTodoItem
          size="medium"
          placeholder="Add Todo"
          onInput={(e) => saveEditedTodo(e, todo.id)}
          contentEditable
          suppressContentEditableWarning="true"
        >
          {todo.todoItem}
        </NoteTitle>
        {hoverID === todo.id && onHover && (
          <Tool
            title="Delete Todo"
            bgImage={DeleteIcon}
            deleteTodo={() => handleDeleteTodo(todo.id)}
          />
        )}
      </TodoListContainer>
    ));

    return (todoList = (
      <div>
        {todoList}
        {doneTodo > 0 && <CompletedTodo doneTodo={doneTodo} />}
        {doneList}
      </div>
    ));
  }

  if (!isEditable && todos) {
    const todoList = todos.map((todo, i) => (
      <TodoListContainer key={i}>
        <Checkbox
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={() => handleCheckbox(todo.id)}
          checked={todo.isDone}
        />
        <NoteTitle size="small">{todo.todoItem}</NoteTitle>
      </TodoListContainer>
    ));

    return todoList;
  }
  return null;
}

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: Why do you need another `setTodos` in `useEffect`?

Comment: Perhaps you should just move `onBlur(todos)` to `useEffect` because you want to call it when todos change?

Comment: My todo items are contentEdiable div. So I need to update its state (todos's content) whenever its content is changed. So I tried to update todo's state onBlur when user typing something, but it lost last character (I guess because of render-cycle).. And I tried to move ```onBlur(todos)``` to ```useEffect``` but ```onBlur(todos)``` has also "set state" so it caused infinite loop. TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `React.useEffect()` is used for performing side effects for a React component. What I believe is that you wish to get the new state rendered on screen after saving the TODO content, and that can be just achieved by an `onChange` handler wherever you are receiving the input for your todos.

```
<TextField onChange={(e) => saveEditedTodos(e, id)} />
```

This will trigger the `saveEditedTodos` callback every time the value of the `TextField` changes. If you want to trigger the callback on clicking a save button, you can add an `onClick` handler in the Button component.

Another scenario what I can imagine is that you're saving your TODOs somewhere, so you want to update the list on the screen after saving the TODO in some storage, in that case you can fetch the value of `todoList` on each save. This can be done inside a `useEffect` hook callback.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetchTodos().then((response) => setTodos(response.data))
})
```

Here `fetchTodos()` is a JS Promise or async function which fetches the updated state of TODOs and sets the received `data` using `setTodos`

Comment: Thank you for answering :) My todo items are "contentEdiable" div. So I cannot use value attribute on change event. (I tried to use onInput but it didn't work..) Instead I chose using onBlur. So whenever contentEditable div's content (todo) is changed, I need to update its state!

Comment: I just tried it but I lost my caret position when I use onKeyUp and also  onInput event.. I guess contentEditable div causes this issue.

Comment: @Suyeon I think it will be best if you switch a contentEditable div with an input field or Text Field for todos if it's possible in your use-case. You can use map function to display the input fields dynamically.

Comment: @ viveknigam3003 Yup I think that can be an alternative. Thank you for helping me :)